# OpenCL type of variable in kernel when the buffer is cl_ulong

Tags: opencl

when i create a buffer with size of cl_ulong such as

```
arrM_obj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_ulong)* arrayWidth * arrayHeight, arrM, &err);
```

in my kernel what is type of global arrM ?

```
__kernel void kernelvoid(__global unsigned long int* m)
```

or

```
__kernel void kernelvoid(__global cl_ulong* m)
```

or can i use

```
__kernel void kernelvoid(__global unsigned long long int* m)
```

for variables size long long int.

what's right? thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the OpenCL C language you use `ulong`.
In the non-OpenCL code it's referred to as `cl_ulong`.

Please see the documentation on [scalar data types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html) for additional information.